# How to <copy> in a <macrodef> in ant?

Tags: ant

I'm trying to copy files in a macro, like so:

```
<project name="why" default="go">
  <macrodef name="copy-some-stuff">
    <attribute name="file.name" />

    <copy todir="/var/tmp">
      <fileset file="${file.name}" />
    </copy>
  </macrodef>

  <target name="go">
    <copy-some-stuff file.name="/etc/hosts" />
  </target>
</project>
```

but I get the following

```
BUILD FAILED
b.xml:3: macrodef doesn't support the nested "copy" element.
```

Any ideas, other than "yes, indeeed, macrodef doesn't support the nested "copy" element." I got that much. I'm looking for why this limitation is here and a possible workaround (without using `antcall`).

Comment: Looks like someone didn't read the manual for macrodef.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try surrounding the `<copy>` element with `<sequential>`:

```
<macrodef name="copy-some-stuff">
   <attribute name="file.name" />
   <sequential>
      <copy todir="/var/tmp">
          <fileset file="@{file.name}" />
      </copy>
   </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I also botched the usage of attributes in the macro. Should be:

          <fileset file="@{file.name}" />

Notice using @ param not $.

Comment: Indeed, didn't notice that. I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Six years later I don't use Ant anymore. IIRC <macrodef> must have a <sequential> to contain any actions